# PHP - A non well formed numeric value encountered

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I tried executing a *MySQL* query within **PHP** (using **Laravel** Eloquent) to insert / update a table column which contains text (json) and MySQL throws the error "A non well formed numeric value encountered".

Table column:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN `indicator` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL;
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO test (`indicator`) VALUES ("{\"legend_label\":\"Received\",\"legend_label_id\":8341,\"table_key\":\"created\"}");
```

Laravel code:

```
$updateQuery = "UPDATE {$tableInfo->{"Table"}} SET `{$columnName}` = :{$columnName}";
try {
  $rowUpdated = DB::connection('mysql')->update($updateQuery, [$columnName => $columnValue]);
  if (!is_int($rowUpdated)) {
    Log::warning("Failed updating column {$columnName} in {$tableInfo->{"Table"}}");
  }
} catch (QueryException $ex) {
  Log::error("ERROR when executing query");
  Log::error("DB ERROR {$ex->getMessage()}");
  Log::error("Data: " .print_r($columnValue, true));
  Log::error("Type: " .gettype($columnValue));
}
```

It does not matter if UPDATE or INSERT is used. Both throw the same exception.
Works when using MySQL Workbench. Does not work in PHP.

Please help!

Comment: _..Does not work in PHP...._ Where is the php code?

Comment: did you try printing your prepared sql statement?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "A non well formed numeric value encountered" is a php error, not a mysql error.

Comment: The prepared statement looks fine. 
`UPDATE test SET \`indicator\` = :indicator`

Comment: Can you explain this line - $updateQuery = "UPDATE {$tableInfo->{"Table"}} SET `{$columnName}` = :{$columnName}"; Why both are columnName?

Comment: Because I just need a key using PDO parameter replacement in a query. The value is assigned to the key when executing the statement `DB::connection('mysql')->update($updateQuery, [$columnName => $columnValue]);`

Comment: Why are you doing this: `$tableInfo->{"Table"}` instead of `$tableInfo->Table` ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was the key of the replacement which did not work correctly. The query works like that:

```
UPDATE {$tableInfo->{"Table"}} SET `{$columnName}` = :columnVal
```

Obviously PHP did not want me to use the column name in a prepared statement.